# Why must parameterless struct constructors be public in C# 6?

Tags: c#, struct

Parameterless struct constructors, which so far have been prohibited in C#, are now implemented in the Visual Studio 14 CTP (CTP 4 at the time of writing) as an experimental feature.

However, such parameterless constructors *must* be public. You cannot make them internal or use any other access modifier.

In the [C# Design Notes for Aug 27, 2014](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/562559), I have found an explanation for this:

> C#, VB and F# will all call an accessible parameterless constructor if they find one. If there is one, but it is not accessible, C# and VB will backfill `default(T)` instead. (F# will complain.)
>
> It is problematic to have successful but different behavior of new S() depending on where you are in the code. To minimize this issue, we should make it so that explicit parameterless constructors have to be public. That way, if you want to replace the “default behavior” you do it everywhere.

What is meant by "depending on where you are in the code", and how does enforcing `public` parameterless constructors solve the issue?

Comment: There were really good reasons for the old rule...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where you are in the code` means that you will get different behaviors depending on the location of the code that uses a struct.

For instance, if you have a parameterless constructor that's marked as internal,  the behavior varies if you create an instance from the same assembly in which the struct is defined or from another assembly.

In first case the parameterless constructor is called because its accessible and in second case default(T) is called. Same situation is enountered for `private` and `protected` constructors.

For example, suppose we have two assemblies, A and B:

```
//Assembly A
public struct SomeStruct
{
   public int x = 0;
   internal SomeStruct()
   { 
       x = 10;
   }
}

public static void DoSomething()
{
      var someStruct = new SomeStruct();
      Console.WriteLine(someStruct.x); // prints 10  
}


//Assembly B
public static void DoAnotherThing()
{
    var someStruct = new SomeStruct();
    Console.WriteLine(someStruct.x); // prints 0
}
```

This leads to inconsistent behavior depending on `where you are in the code` and the reason why they forced using `public` constructors.

Answer (score 3):

You can be "in a place in the code" in the following meaning:

- in the context of your struct, i.e.:

```
struct X
{
    //...

    public X CreateNew() { return new X(); }
}
```

- in the context of your assembly:

```
new X();  // from the same assembly
```

- in another assembly

```
new X(); // from another assembly
```

So, the mechanism you speak of, would have to behave differently for exactly the same piece of code (`new X();`), in each of these contexts. In the first example, you can use the constructor regardless of its access modifier. In the second example, you can access one if it's `public` or `internal`. In the third one, it could've been used only if it's `public`.

Making it `public` simplifies the situation, as it will be accessible in all of these contexts.